# Chrome form.submit() handler ignores required fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome, required

I expected that calling `.submit()` on a `<form>` with javascript would call the validation functions on each `<input/>`, just like clicking a submit button.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this behavior by design?

```html
<form name="nameForm" action="#" method="post"
      onsubmit="this.name.value = this.name.value + ' (' + location.hostname + ')'">
  <input type="text" name="name"
         placeholder="Your name" required="required" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<p>This form has a <code>required</code> field.</p>
<p>
  But <a href="javascript:document.nameForm.submit()">this link</a>
  which calls the form's <code>submit()</code> function doesn't fire
  the <code>required</code> handler.
</p>
```

Ignore the console error on submit. I have a real submit action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to call `document.nameForm.commit.click()` from the link, but I still don't understand why the submit action is different.